# Why am I getting "the best overloaded List<DelegationInformation> add method for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to return the `delInfo` variable and the data inside it. But I can't understand what exactly going wrong with it?

I am getting the error

> The best overloaded List add method for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Here's my code:

```
public List<DelegationInformation> GetDelegations(string profileUid, List<int> userPrivilegeIds)
{
    using (var context = GetDBContext())
    {
        var delInfo =
            (
                from delegation in context.vw_Delegations
                where delegation.Delegator == profileUid && userPrivilegeIds.Contains(delegation.AccessPrivilegeID)
                select new DelegationInformation()
                {
                    id = delegation.DelegationID,
                    DelegationId = delegation.DelegationID,
                    AccessPrivilegeId = delegation.AccessPrivilegeID,
                    AccessPrivilegeKey = delegation.AccessPrivilegeKey,
                    AccessPrivilegeName = delegation.AccessPrivilegeName,
                    Enabled = delegation.Status,
                    IsPermanent = delegation.isPermanent.HasValue ? delegation.isPermanent.Value : false,
                    Delegatee = delegation.Delegatee,
                    DelegateeFirstName = delegation.DelegateeFirstName,
                    DelegateeLastName = delegation.DelegateeLastName,
                    Delegator = delegation.Delegator,
                    DelegatorFirstName = delegation.DelegatorFirstName,
                    DelegatorLastName = delegation.DelegatorLastName,
                    StartDate = delegation.StartDate,
                    EndDate = delegation.EndDate,
                    ChangedBy = delegation.ChangedBy,
                    ChangedOn = delegation.ChangedOn,
                }
            ).ToList();

        foreach (var item in delInfo)
        {
            item.DelegateeFullName = ARMCommon.GetProfileDisplayName(item.Delegatee);
            item.DelegatorFullName = ARMCommon.GetProfileDisplayName(item.Delegator);
        }

        return new List<DelegationInformation>
        {
           delInfo
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `return` statement is incorrect, use `AddRange` or just `return delInfo;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

return should have been

```
return delInfo;
```

Comment: How does it differ from another answer?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  no difference.. Its me who didn't see that answer before writing mine

Answer (score 1):

Just return delInfo as it is already list

```
return delInfo;
```